# Is there an analogue of GhostDoc in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-documentation

I'm looking for something like GhostDoc for VS Code (C#), but to no avail. Anyone knows anything?

I've only found [an "old" VS-like extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment) which makes XML comments available when you type '///', but it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentThis is available with similar features.

Comment: Thank you, but it's TS/JS-oriented, not C#

Comment: DocumentThis extension is available for Visual Code.
First Install it from extensions then run below shortcut to run DocumentThis.
Ctrl+Alt+D and again Ctrl+Alt+D